# Hiding master for nested UISplitViewControlles's details

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

Apple is encouraging us to use `UISplitViewController` for Universal apps, but anytime I try it I face a brick wall.
I've created my app based on `UINavigationController` as it was iPhone only so far, but now with switching to Universal we want to have a Master-Details for one screen, so it was *natural* for me to reach for `UISplitViewController`. I've started simple with **Master-Detail App Template** and I just wanted to check whether it resizes correctly for different devices and screen sizes.
Template is clear and everything works smooth, but as I've mentioned - I want this Master-Detail to be visible only for one screen at the moment (maybe more in the future), so... I've added new View Controller to the Storyboard and now it look like:
[image]
Everything works great on iPhones, but when it comes to iPads I can see a Master View Controller all the time. What I want to achieve is to hide it once we get deeper in the Details View Controller hierarchy. **Is it actually possible?**
Since it's only for one view I was also thinking about creating separate Storyboard for iPad and have this one screen being represented as `UIViewController` with two `UIContainerView`s, but I'm not sure whether it's worth an overhead with maintaining 2 Storyboards just for this...

Answer (score 0):

At launch did you set the preferredDisplayMode to .primaryHidden? For example, if your reference to the split view controller is **splitviewctlr**, try this at launch:

```
splitviewctlr.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryHidden
```

That should hide the primary when on the iPad.

You should also assign a delegate for the split view controller and implement the **targetDisplayModeForAction(in:)** method in the delegate to control which controller appears when the user clicks the back button.

Another useful property of the split view controller is **isCollapsed**, a boolean to test whether the interface is collapsed to the detail controller or not.